# Trying to close a Window a second time after canceling throws an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an interface:

```
public interface ICloseable
{
    event EventHandler Closing;
    event EventHandler Closed;
    void Close();
}
```

which I'm implementing in my `ViewModel`:

```
public class TestViewModel : ICloseable
{
    public event EventHandler Closing;
    public event EventHandler Closed;

    public void Close()
    {
        RaiseEvent(Closing);
        
        // do some cleaning...
        
        RaiseEvent(Closed);
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseEvent(EventHandler handler)
    {
        handler?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

This `TestViewModel` is set as the `DataContext` of the following `TestView`:

```
public partial class TestView : Window
{
    private bool _contextClosed = false; // true if DataContext has been closed

    public TestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var context = new TestViewModel();

        Closing += TestView_Closing;
        DataContext = context;

        context.Closed += TestViewModel_Closed;
    }

    private void TestView_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = DataContext as ICloseable;
        if (!_contextClosed)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            context.Close();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void TestViewModel_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _contextClosed = true;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Close());
    }

    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to close `TestView` (either by clicking 'X' on the titlebar or the `TestButton`), I get the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing.'`

at the line:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Close());
```

in the `TestViewModel_Closed` method.

**I am wondering why this is happening even though I set `e.Cancel = true` the first time `TestView_Closing` is called.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem is perhaps that all calls are synchronous, i.e. you are eventually calling Window.Close from Window.Closing. As a note, you must not use the `as` operator without checking the result for null. You should instead use a type cast: `var context = (ICloseable)DataContext;`

Comment: @Clemens Just to get a clarification, I'm calling the `View`'s `Close()` from the `TestViewModel_Closed` method, which is raised by `TestViewModel`, not `TestView`. But is that still being treated as synchronous?

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception, you will see what happened.

Comment: Use the asynchronous BeginInvoke instead of Invoke: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(Close));`

Comment: @Clemens That seems to have done the trick! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a synchronous method call chain from the `TestView_Closing` event handler to the `Close` call in the Disaptcher Action, which can be seen in the stack trace of the exception:

```
at System.Windows.Window.VerifyNotClosing()
at System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(Boolean shutdown, Boolean ignoreCancel)
at System.Windows.Window.Close()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
at ViewModelClosing.TestView.TestViewModel_Closed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Usr\Projekte\StackOverflow\ViewModelClosing\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 50
at ViewModelClosing.TestViewModel.RaiseEvent(EventHandler handler) in C:\Usr\Projekte\StackOverflow\ViewModelClosing\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 80
at ViewModelClosing.TestViewModel.Close() in C:\Usr\Projekte\StackOverflow\ViewModelClosing\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 75
at ViewModelClosing.TestView.TestView_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) in C:\Usr\Projekte\StackOverflow\ViewModelClosing\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 43
at System.Windows.Window.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.WmClose()
```

You should replace

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Close());
```

by the asynchronous call

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(Close));
```

where `Dispatcher` is a property of the Window class. There is no need to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution and explanation. I had no clue about this.